# What native search engine can be used for my use case?

Tags: android, search, kotlin, native, search-engine

I am working on an android application where some secured data will be stored in android device and frequently be queried from web app side. Right now I am storing the data in `SQLite` DB. When the application is opening I am loading the full data from DB and preparing a filter map for efficient in memory queries for web app. However, for large amount of data `in-memory` query might not be a scalable solution. My search queries are basically full text search. Where can I start from?

#### Update 1

As suggested by Gaurav, I am trying to use virtual table,

```
private const val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ${FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME} USING FTS5 (" +
            "${FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE}," +
            "${FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE})"
```

It gives me error while creating table,

> [CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE entry USING FTS5 (title,subtitle);] no such module: FTS5

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.achellies.kotlin, PID: 30458
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.achellies.kotlin/com.achellies.kotlin.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such module: FTS5 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such module: FTS5 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:946)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2228)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:2155)
    at com.achellies.kotlin.FeedReaderDbHelper.onCreate(FeedReaderDbHelper.kt:19)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:393)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
    at com.achellies.kotlin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

#### Update 2

```
private const val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ${FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME} USING FTS4 (" +
            "${FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE}," +
            "${FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE})"
```

This works fine for me. But I cannot run raw query with sanitized input.

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM entry WHERE title MATCH '?'"
        val args = arrayOf("Test")
        val cursor: Cursor? = db.rawQuery(query, args)
```

Runtime error,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.achellies.kotlin/com.achellies.kotlin.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

Comment: 17k rep and 8 years on this site, you should know by now that asking for library recommendations is off topic and will get your question closed

Comment: @TimCastelijns this post already came to a specific problem. And right now I am discussing about specific issue with someone who has a good intention to help. Requesting you to revert back your close vote.

Comment: as long as your question is "I want to apply if there is well known data query framework or library in my application which can run queries on database" it doesn't matter what you are discussing with him or what his intentions are. Maybe update your question is better

Comment: @TimCastelijns I updated the post. Requesting to revert the vote for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite provides a Full Text Search Option. I have used it successfully for my app that searches on 0.22 Million strings in real-time.

You need to create A virtual table. And insert all your data in this table.Then you need to update this table when new data comes along.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE table_name 
USING FTS4(column1,column2...);
```

ex -

```
public boolean createFTS4Table() {
        database = getWritableDatabase();
        boolean success = true;
        try {

            database.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE if not exists fts_dict USING fts4 (id ,word)");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO fts_dict SELECT rowid,word FROM entries");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "ERROR in FTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return success;

    }
```

For searching you can use MATCH -

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE posts MATCH 'fts5';
```

Java -

```
getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + FTS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE word match ?", new String[]{word + "*"}
```

For more in-depth documentation -

http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/

Comment: Gaurav, I am getting error `no such module: FTS5 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])`. Did you mean virtual table is supported in Android default SQLite fw or i need gradle support?

Comment: I think android has support upto FTS4 (The one I used). I have changed the syntax in the post.

Comment: Gaurav, are you sure your example query string is correct? `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts MATCH 'fts5';` posts is table name and 2nd posts is what? It makes confusion.

Comment: As I can see you are using FTS5 to create the table, please use fts4. (See java example). Also, I have added java code for searching as well. (I don't know kotlin sorry!)

Comment: Gaurav, thanks for your support. However I cannot bind input when using FTS4 rawQuery. Can you help on my updated post?

Comment: Maybe drop the quotes around ?

Comment: Thanks for your support and time Gaurav

Comment: Gaurav is it possible to combine CipherSQL and FTS together?